# PHP: How to install the GD Modul for making and editing images on the fly?

Tags: php, image, installation, gd

Im confused about the things in the internet...

must I install the GD Library on my webserver.. it sounds like i must install it on my computer.

so please i need an easy step by step way to install it on my webserver.

thx in advance.. and sry for my bad english.

edit: solved! thx!

Comment: Whats your hosting environment?

Comment: If you have the time to edit the question and state it is solved, you ought to have enough time to accept an answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your have sudo privileges and command line access to the server hosting your site, you should do the following to get the PHP graphics library that Elementor requires to be enabled.

1) sudo apt-get install php-gd

2) In php.ini (normally /ete/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini):

**CHANGE**

;extension=php_gd2.dll

to

extension=php_gd2.dll

(You're just un-commenting it)

3) Restart Apache: sudo service apache2 restart

Hope this helps someone!!!

Comment: that is the right solution. In my case i didn't remove comment from dll

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% you have to have to enable it, I believe it just helps php overall with graphics processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting it yourself and you installed PHP properly, you just have to enable `php_gd2` in php.ini.

Comment: ... its an free webserver ... byethost.

so i cannot (or dont know how to) see or edit the php.ini

Comment: Bytehost page says GD and ImageMagick are enabled: http://bytehost.tk/free-web-hosting.html

Comment: I have done this, and restarted apache. This did not solve the issue for me.

Comment: Please see my answer below if you have sudo access to the server hosting the site.

Answer (score 1):

create a simple php script like this

`<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>`

run the script and search for php_gd2. If you did not find it... then ...

Comment: ...then what? would be nice if your answer where complete.

Comment: i tried the info.. but dont found the php_gd2 or somthing near.

but stillstanding said it must be there... maybe it must be enebled somewhere.. i wil look for it. thx

Comment: Within your document ( igramul.byethost6.com/maptest.php ) I found "GD" - and its enabled. Use your browser search (ctrl/apple + F)

Comment: .. ? i ried.. an it found nothing.. weird.. ok... 

so i try to enable it. or something... thx!

Comment: Ok. Gd is enabled.Go codding `GD Support | enabled GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible) `

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have GD installed somewhere, either on your development/production server or on a shared service host. Since there is no information about your web server, this is more of a general answer. All installation instructions can be found in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and in the package itself.

Installing it on Ubuntu for example is as simple as running `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`.

To check whether it is successfully installed, run `php -m | grep gd` in CLI or create a simple PHP script `<?php phpinfo()` and search for GD.

In either case, make sure to have `extension=gd.so` in your `php.ini` file and restart Apache, again for Ubuntu `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Added: Based on your additional [information](http://igramul.byethost6.com/maptest.php), you already have GD installed and enabled and the [Bytehost](http://bytehost.tk/free-web-hosting.html) states both GD and Image Magick are enabled.